# Adding Weighted Points to Multiple Maps Plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, gis, visualization, r-sp

How is it possible to generate the following plot using `spplot` or `ggplot`. I tried both ways, but unfortunately didn't prevail in any of them.
The porblem I am faced is connected with the **appropiate** adding points to the maps.
All necessary data (`.shp,.prj,.dbf,.shx`) you need to reproduce the problem are available [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/sr9jq5hnk7610gh/AACpt_vghBlruGDgBBwPKMKLa?dl=0)

My code is following:

```
    library(sp)
    library(maptools)
    library(RColorBrewer)
    germK <- readShapePoly("C:/Users/XYZ/Dropbox/R Skripts/PolygonG/vg250_krs.shp")
    germK <- germK[germK@data$GF==4,]
    germK@data$EWZ2 <- cut(germK@data$EWZ, breaks=quantile(germK@data$EWZ, 1:10/10))
    germK@data$EWZ <- germK@data$EWZ2
    mypalette <- rev(brewer.pal(9, "RdYlGn"))
    pts1 <- list("sp.points", germK, pch = 21,lwd=2,cex=sample(1:412,412)/200, col = "black")
    pts2 <- list("sp.points", germK, pch = 21,lwd=2,cex=sample(1:412,412)/200, col = "black")
    p.layout <- list(pts1,pts2)
    spplot(germK,zcol=c("EWZ","EWZ2"), sp.layout = p.layout, col.regions=mypalette)
```

The result I got by carrying out the upper code lines is:
[image]

The points from `pts1` have to be plotted in the first map, and respectively the points from `pts2` should be depictied on the second map. In my case you can see both points are present in both maps. Any idea how to settle the problem?

Recently, I have found a way for proper depicting points, but by this the titles disappear:

```
p1 <- spplot(germK,zcol="EWZ", sp.layout = pts1, col.regions=mypalette,
                         names.attr="X")
p2 <- spplot(germK,zcol="EWZ", sp.layout=pts2, col.regions=mypalette,
                         names.attr="Y")
p3 <- c(p1,p2, layout=c(2,1))
p3
```

After this part of code I am getting the desired look, which is not quite pretty but acceptable.
[image]
 Any help will be *highly* appriciated!

Comment: I must be missing something, but it looks from your code like the sets of points are the same and are plotted on the same geography.  How should the EWZ2 plot then look different?

Comment: I invested some time to look for your data, but I could not identify which vg files you have. I am afraid that just having the .shp file does not allow us to import data in R. As @lawyeR said, it seems to me that your EWZ and EWZ2 are identical. If you need any help, would you be able to specify which data you have? As far as I searched, there are various zip files. [This](http://www.geodatenzentrum.de/geodaten/gdz_rahmen.gdz_div?gdz_spr=eng&gdz_akt_zeile=5&gdz_anz_zeile=1&gdz_unt_zeile=14&gdz_user_id=0) is where I ended up reaching.

Comment: The background of both maps ought to be the same. The only difference between two graphs occure in points. In my case I just generated a set of points randomly using *sample* of the length of considered Polygons  (412).  @jazzurro you are completly right I forgot to add neseccery files for loading maps. Although you exactly found the source the data come from.

Comment: I made changes in the Data you need to load in R Environment, now it is to work flawless. Thanks for your efforts. I was trying to do this with *ggplot* but the problem with the points is still present even there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can make use of the `which` argument:

```
pts1 <- list("sp.points", germK, pch = 21,lwd=2,cex=sample(1:412,412)/200, col = "black", which = 1)
pts2 <- list("sp.points", germK, pch = 21,lwd=2,cex=sample(1:412,412)/200, col = "black", which = 2)

spplot(germK,zcol=c("EWZ","EWZ2"), sp.layout = list(pts1, pts2), col.regions=mypalette)
```

Comment: very nice solution @rengis! I'd like it.